# .each loop with multidimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to loop through below code and trying to get values in an array. Since there are two input fields for every form-group, i know i need to store all in 2D array. I have tried, but its not retrieving in array correctly. I have used .each for this. But stuck and not getting correct array. Also new form group will add on clicking add new. Please help me solving this.

```
<div class="form-group sm-tableBox">
    <div class="input-box">
        <strong>1st</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" name="" class="form-control" />
        <span class="hint">mm</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box ico">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" name="" class="form-control" />
        <span class="hint">mm</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group sm-tableBox">
    <div class="input-box">
        <strong>2nd</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" name="" class="form-control" />
        <span class="hint">mm</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box ico">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" name="" class="form-control" />
        <span class="hint">mm</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group sm-tableBox">
    <div class="input-box">
        <strong>3rd</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" name="" class="form-control" />
        <span class="hint">mm</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box ico">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" name="" class="form-control" />
        <span class="hint">mm</span>
    </div>
</div>



$(".btn-submit").click(function() {
    var i = 0;
    var j = 0;
    var parent = [];
    var child = [];
    $(" .form-group").each(function(){
        $(".input-box").each(function(){
            child[j] = $r('input[class=form-control]').val();
            j++;
        });
        parent[i] = child[j];
        i++;
        j=0;
    });
    console.log(parent);
```

Comment: can you show us your .each code?

Comment: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself."*

Comment: *"I have tried"* ... you should be showing us what you tried so people can help fix that...not write a complete solution for you since this isn't a code writing service

Comment: please see updated question.

Comment: Your main issue is not looking at only inputs within instance of `$(" .form-group")` ....  `$(" .form-group").each(function(i){ $(this).find(".input-box").each....` otherwise you are iterating every `$(".input-box")` in page each time. Notice use of `$(this).find()`. Inside that inner `each` use `this.value` or `$(this).val()` for value of input instance

Comment: thanks for valid inputs. I will try.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do with pure JS like this

```js
var nodes = document.querySelectorAll(".form-group"),
     divs = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes,0),
      arr = [],
updateArr = e => {arr = divs.map(d => Array.prototype.slice.call(d.querySelectorAll(".form-control")).reduce((v,e) => v.concat(e.value),[])); console.log(JSON.stringify(arr))};

divs.forEach(d => d.addEventListener("change",updateArr,false));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
<div class="form-group sm-tableBox">
    <div class="input-box">
        <strong>1st</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" name="" class="form-control" />
        <span class="hint">mm</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box ico">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" name="" class="form-control" />
        <span class="hint">mm</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group sm-tableBox">
    <div class="input-box">
        <strong>2nd</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" name="" class="form-control" />
        <span class="hint">mm</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box ico">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" name="" class="form-control" />
        <span class="hint">mm</span>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group sm-tableBox">
    <div class="input-box">
        <strong>3rd</strong>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" name="" class="form-control" />
        <span class="hint">mm</span>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box ico">
        <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="number" name="" class="form-control" />
        <span class="hint">mm</span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made solution.See below.

```
 $r(".btn-submit").click(function() {  
    var parent = [];
    var child = []; 
    $r(".worktopmeas").each(function(){
        $r(this).find(".form-control").each(function(){
            if($r(this).val()!="")
            child.push($r(this).val());  
        });
        if(child.length!=0)
             parent.push([child[0],child[1]]);
        child.length = 0;
        //console.log(child);

    });
    console.log(parent);
```

Just in case if any others stuck with same. :)